# Fedora 30 : Laptop won't shutdown/reboot or hibernate

Tags: fedora, shutdown, laptop, reboot, hibernate

I've installed `f30`and I've come across this issue : when I power on my laptop and close the lid, the system gets hibernated as I told it to do.

When I open the lid the system is up and running again but when I re-close it, the laptop doesn't hibernate! It behaves as nothing happened.

In addition,  when the screen remains inactive for some time and I am required to type my password, it takes about 15 seconds to log in again. This happens when opening the lid, after the first successful hibernation.

I also tried to shutdown the system by typing `sudo poweroff`, but for about an hour I was seeing things like the following on my screen so I decided to power it of manually by pressing the power button.

https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/SnKIMmbOm5bfYpu
https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/NpYvhtj4Js58wHw

I addition, I noticed that this behaviour takes place once a program that I use (`texmaker`) freezes. This is what `journalctl -r` got me, once I noticed the freezing

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-08-10 13:27:14 CEST, end at Wed 2019-08-28 15:29:47 CEST. --
Aug 28 15:29:47 pcen35240 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_MUTEX_NOT_ACQUIRED) (20190509/psparse-529)
Aug 28 15:29:47 pcen35240 kernel: ACPI Error: Cannot release Mutex [PATM], not acquired (20190509/exmutex-357)
Aug 28 15:29:16 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: # watch_established: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0)
Aug 28 15:29:16 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: # unwatch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (active: 0, establishing: 1)
Aug 28 15:29:16 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: # watch_fast: "/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
Aug 28 15:29:16 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: # _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
Aug 28 15:29:16 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: # _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation gvfs (GDaemonVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566998851,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 1 is not equal to the current group from the event: 0
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566998849,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 1 is not equal to the current group from the event: 0
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566998848,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 1 is not equal to the current group from the event: 0
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566998564,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566998557,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997851,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997849,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997848,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997847,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997844,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997843,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997841,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997817,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997816,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997762,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 1 is not equal to the current group from the event: 0
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997755,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 1 is not equal to the current group from the event: 0
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997742,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997741,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:27:31 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: ![1566997738,000,xklavier_evt_xkb.c:xkl_xkb_process_x_event/]         ATTENTION! Currently cached group 0 is not equal to the current group from the event: 1
Aug 28 15:26:46 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: Cinnamon warning: Log level 128: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested)
Aug 28 15:24:45 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: Cinnamon warning: Log level 128: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested)
Aug 28 15:24:18 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 15:24:00 pcen35240 tracker-miner-f[2234]: Could not process 'file:///home/astamato/Documents/n_ToF/240Pu/Papers/PRC/tex/240Pu.synctex(busy)': Error when getting information for file “/home/astamato/Documents/n_ToF/240Pu/Papers/PRC>
Aug 28 15:23:48 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 28 15:23:48 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Aug 28 15:22:29 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: Cinnamon warning: Log level 128: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested)
Aug 28 15:19:46 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: Cinnamon warning: Log level 128: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested)
Aug 28 15:18:19 pcen35240 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=dnf-makecache comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Aug 28 15:18:19 pcen35240 audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=dnf-makecache comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
Aug 28 15:18:19 pcen35240 systemd[1]: Started dnf makecache.
Aug 28 15:18:19 pcen35240 systemd[1]: dnf-makecache.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 15:18:19 pcen35240 dnf[20705]: Metadata cache refreshed recently.
Aug 28 15:18:18 pcen35240 systemd[1]: Starting dnf makecache...
Aug 28 15:18:18 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 15:17:56 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 28 15:17:56 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Aug 28 15:16:52 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 15:16:41 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 28 15:16:41 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Aug 28 15:15:51 pcen35240 /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1716]: Cinnamon warning: Log level 128: posix_spawn avoided (automatic reaping requested) (fd close requested)
Aug 28 15:15:19 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 15:15:08 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 28 15:15:08 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Aug 28 15:14:27 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 15:14:16 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 28 15:14:16 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Aug 28 15:14:04 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Aug 28 15:13:53 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Aug 28 15:13:53 pcen35240 systemd[1677]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
```

This is also followed by `grub` not loading when powering on the laptop, after the hardware shutdown. I am not sure if all these are connected to each other.

Any idea on what might be the issue and how to track it down?

---

Here is the of [`journal -- system` (26 Aug 2019)](https://cernbox.cern.ch/index.php/s/twQ3SXDtJEDHUPd)

And here is my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
```